# Load file into CKEditor textarea via javascript, PHP and select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor

Thanks to @AlejandroIván ([Load file into CKEditor textarea using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642996/load-file-into-ckeditor-textarea-using-javascript)) got CKEditor to display uploaded files. Working great...

BUT, causing issues with younger users. They do not always upload the correct file.

What we are attempting to do in classroom is load premade layouts into CKEditor via PHP & select menu. Since JSFiddle does not process PHP, cannot give working example.

The JSFiddle with working upload function is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0gtpvvqa/).

Here is the sample with select menu and PHP we have been testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Pick a Layout</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,300,500,600,700&subset=latin,devanagari,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css'  href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topdiv">
Pick Your Layout
</div>


<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
</textarea>
<br />
<input name="file" type="file" id="files" class="form-control" value="">

<br />


<div>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <strong>Pick Your Flavor</strong>
  </td>    
 </tr>
 <tr>

<td class="indtd">
<p>
<select name="file" id="files" onChange="window.location='pickckeditor.php?template='+this.value">
<option>Choose Layout</option>
<option value="features">Features</option>
<option value="3colx2">Three Col X2</option>
<option value="3colx1">Three Col X1</option>
</select>
</p>

<?php

$Template = $_REQUEST["template"];

if ($Template == "features"){

echo "<section id='features'>
<div class='title'>
<h2 class='flex fadeInUp animated'>The best features</h2>
<p class='description flex fadeInUp animated'>With features engineered from best practices used by leading property management companies worldwide.</p>
</div>
<!--end title-->
<div class='para flex fadeInRight animated animated'>
<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an...</p>
</div>
<br />
<!--end para-->
<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-cogs'></i>
<h3>Designed with Pride</h3>
<p>Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra eu libero sit amet quam egestas sempe</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group'></i>
<h3>Support & coffee</h3>
<p>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.</p>
</div><!--end col-md-4-->
</div><!--end row-->
<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-cogs'></i>
<h3>Designed with Pride</h3>
<p>Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra eu libero sit amet quam egestas sempe</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group'></i>
<h3>Support & coffee</h3>
<p>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.</p>
</div><!--end col-md-4-->
</div><!--end row-->
<div class='para flex fadeInLeft animated animated'>
<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an...</p>
</div>
</section><!--end section-->";

}

elseif ($Template == "3colx2"){

echo "<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 facenter caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-cogs feature' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Quality Designed</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group' style='color: rgb(0, 0, 51);'></i>
<h3>Easy to Use</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4--></div>
<!--end 3-col row-->
<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 facenter caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-cogs' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Designed Clean</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group' style='color: rgb(0, 0, 51);'></i>
<h3>Easy to Use</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4--></div>";

}

elseif ($Template == "3colx1"){

echo "<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 facenter caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-cogs feature' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Quality Designed</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group' style='color: rgb(0, 0, 51);'></i>
<h3>Easy to Use</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4--></div>
<!--end 3-col row-->";

}

else{

echo ("Select a layout from dropdown");

}

?>

</td>
</tr>
 </table>
 </div>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

    $(document).ready(function() {
    function readTextFile(file, callback, encoding) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
                    callback(this.result);
                });
                if (encoding) reader.readAsText(file, encoding);
                else reader.readAsText(file);
            }

            function fileChosen(input, output) {
                if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
                    readTextFile(
                        input.files[0],
                        function (str) {
                  output.setData(str);
                  output.updateElement();
                        }
                    );
                }
            }

            $('#files').on('change', function () {
            var result = $("#files").text();
                fileChosen(this, CKEDITOR.instances.editor1);
            });
        });
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

We have tried many different onChange events without any success and know this is not correct, but out of ideas:

```
<select name="file" id="files" onChange="window.location='pickckeditor.php?template='+this.value">
```

Do not need the file input (upload) function and select option together, so file input can go away if need be.

**Recap:** *Need to have template snippet from the echos loaded into CKEditor after user selects from drop down menu.*

Had found [this info](http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/65962-convert-select-box-input.html) and seemed headed in right way, but still no dice.

Is this possible or have we been spinning our wheels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A student came up with a "down and dirty" solution for us. It may not be best for live production but ours is used in closed local server environment.

**PHP File**:

```
<?php
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
require_once 'config.php';
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Pick a Layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,300,500,600,700&subset=latin,devanagari,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css'  href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>

        // The instanceReady event is fired, when an instance of CKEditor has finished
        // its initialization.
        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
            // Show this sample buttons.
            document.getElementById( 'eButtons' ).style.display = 'block';
        });

        function InsertHTML() {
            // Get the editor instance that we want to interact with.
            var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
            var value = document.getElementById( 'htmlArea2' ).value;

            // Check the active editing mode.
            if ( editor.mode == 'wysiwyg' )
            {
                // Insert HTML code.
                // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml
                editor.insertHtml( value );
            }
            else
                alert( 'You must be in WYSIWYG mode!' );
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="description">
    <p>
        Down and dirty way to insert content into CKEditor via dropdown select menu.
    </p>
    </div>

    <!-- This <div> holds alert messages to be display in the sample page. -->
    <div id="alerts">
        <noscript>
            <p>
                <strong>CKEditor requires JavaScript to run</strong>. In a browser with no JavaScript
                support, like yours, you should still see the contents (HTML data) and you should
                be able to edit it normally, without a rich editor interface.
            </p>
        </noscript>
    </div>

            <p id="eMessage">
        </p>

        <div id="eButtons" style="display: none">

            <select name="select" id="htmlArea2" onchange="InsertHTML();">
            <option>Choose Layout</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $features;?>">Features</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $threecolx1;?>">Three Col X1</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $threecolx2;?>">Three Col X2</option>
            </select>

        </div>
        <br />
        <textarea style="width:100%;" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">Down and dirty</textarea>

        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with an CKEditor instance.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                contentsCss: [ 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,300,500,600,700&subset=latin,devanagari,latin-ext'],
            });
            CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
            CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = false;
            CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false;
            CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['fa'] = false;
        </script>



    <div id="footer">
        <hr>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Config File:**

```
<?php 
$features = "<section id='features'>
<div class='title'>
<h2 class='flex fadeInUp animated'>The best features</h2>
<p class='description flex fadeInUp animated'>With features engineered from best practices used by leading property management companies worldwide.</p>
</div>
<!--end title-->
<div class='para flex fadeInRight animated animated'>
<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an...</p>
</div>
<br />
<!--end para-->
<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-cogs'></i>
<h3>Designed with Pride</h3>
<p>Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra eu libero sit amet quam egestas sempe</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group'></i>
<h3>Support & coffee</h3>
<p>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.</p>
</div><!--end col-md-4-->
</div><!--end row-->
<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-cogs'></i>
<h3>Designed with Pride</h3>
<p>Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra eu libero sit amet quam egestas sempe</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group'></i>
<h3>Support & coffee</h3>
<p>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.</p>
</div><!--end col-md-4-->
</div><!--end row-->
<div class='para flex fadeInLeft animated animated'>
<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an...</p>
</div>
</section><!--end section-->";
$threecolx1 = "<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 facenter caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-cogs feature' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Quality Designed</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group' style='color: rgb(0, 0, 51);'></i>
<h3>Easy to Use</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4--></div>
<!--end 3-col row-->";
$threecolx2 = "<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 facenter caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-cogs feature' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Quality Designed</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group' style='color: rgb(0, 0, 51);'></i>
<h3>Easy to Use</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4--></div>
<!--end 3-col row-->
<div class='row text-center'>
<div class='col-md-4 facenter caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.1s'><i class='fa fa-cogs' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Designed Clean</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.3s'><i class='fa fa-object-group' style='color: rgb(0, 0, 51);'></i>
<h3>Easy to Use</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4-->
<div class='col-md-4 caption flex fadeInUp animated animated' data-wow-delay='0.5s'><i class='fa fa-keyboard-o' style='color: rgb(153, 0, 0);'></i>
<h3>Clean Code</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. 0123456789. The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown foxs back.</p>
</div>
<!--end col-md-4--></div>";
?>
```

**Again, we are in closed server environment and I caution anyone** using "CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;" to fully understand before using on live production server.

Hope this will be of use to others...